# Logging In before doing tests in capybara

Tags: devise, capybara, rspec-rails

I want to test my create user function in ruby on rails using capybara but I am always redirected to the login page. Is there a way that I can test the create function without logging in?

`require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Users", :type =>
:feature do
    before do
        begin
          # login_as(FactoryBot.create(:user)).
          @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        rescue StandardError => e
            puts "#{e.message}"
        end
    end

```
it "Creates a new User" do
    begin
       visit user_session_path
        #visit "/"
            fill_in :first_name, :with => "{@user.first_name}"
            fill_in "middle_name", :with => "{@user.middle_name}"
            fill_in "last_name", :with => "{@user.last_name}"
            fill_in "username", :with => "{@user.username}"
            click_button "Create User"

    rescue StandardError => e
       puts "#{e.message}"
    end
end
```

end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not fully clear whether you're talking about a user that has the rights to create other users, or you just have a user sign up page on your app. The first part of this answer is for the former.

You can't test the page in a feature test without logging in (unless the page doesn't require a user to be logged in) but using the Devise helpers you can skip the step of actually going to the login page and logging in. See https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

Wherever you're configuring RSpec include the Warden helpers

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
end
```

Then in your test use the `login_as` helper to log in as a user that has rights to create a user

```
...
login_as(FactoryBot.create(:admin)) # assumes you have a factory named `admin` that will create a user with the permissions to create other users

visit 'whatever page allows creating a new user'

new_user = FactoryBot.build(:user) # don't create here because you don't want it saved 

fill_in "first_name", with: new_user.first_name
fill_in "middle_name", with: new_user.middle_name
fill_in "last_name", with: new_user.last_name
fill_in "username", with: new_user.username
click_button "Create User"

expect(page).to have_text "Successfully created new user!"
...
```

---

For the second interpretation of you question, if you just have a signup page where people can create a user, then you either don't have the authentication requirements correctly set for the controller action or the fact that you're creating the user in the DB before filling in the info in the UI is creating a collision on a unique field. You can fix that by just building the FactoryBot user rather than creating

```
...
user = FactoryBot.build(:user) # will build a valid user but won't commit it to the DB
fill_in :first_name, with: user.first_name
fill_in "middle_name", with: user.middle_name
fill_in "last_name", with: user.last_name
fill_in "username", with: user.username
click_button "Create User"

# expectation on whatever should happen in the UI goes here
```

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I have an admin that creates a user and also I have  user that can only edit his/her profile. I am testing the admin side.

Comment: I want to sign in as an admin then directly goes to create user. I have a row in the user table as user_role to check if it is an admin or just a user.

Comment: @dubiousconquest That's what the first half of my answer would do, add an :admin factory that extends the :user factory- https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#inheritance -  (or add an :admin trait - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits -  so you could do `FactoryBot.create(:user, :admin)` and you should be good to go

Comment: so I have this factoryBot 
class Users < ApplicationRecord
 FactoryBot.define do
   factory :user do
     first_name { "System" }
     last_name  { "Administrator" }
    
      trait :admin do 
       admin { true }
     end
   end
 end
end 

and getting an error of undefined method 'admin' and unable t find visible field first name

Comment: I'm completely lost

Comment: Your trait needs to set user_role because your model doesn’t have an admin field - `trait :admin do user_role {“admin”} end`.- depending on what your user_role field takes